# How to change the ipython notebook format?

Tags: ipython

I want to change ipython notebook font type and color theme . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I invite you to read [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/Carreau/posts/master/Blog1.ipynb)
 and follow the links to next post that show you how to make a theme selector for dev version. There are also a few links on interesting theme for the notebook, as well as explanation at what won't work in next release.

In short, use `custom.css` in your profile if you have a recent enough version. Other methods will be deprecated soon enough.